# unable to map 2 address in Employee class in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In my project there are two bean classes Employee and Address

i want to use mapping for this. below is the table that i want to create using hibernate

```
Employee table
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id       |    username   |  password  | permanent_address | residential_address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               abc            abc            1                   2


Address table
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    id       |    address_line1   |  address_line2  | city | country| .....
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1               aaaaa           bbbbbb            ppp    india               

    2               ssss           ddddd              fff    india
```

here two address one is residential and second is permanent address and both are mapped in employee table for id 1 and id 2

how can i create my beans classes for this.

below is what i am trying

```
package com.perennial.beans.employee;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address1")
    private Address address1;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address2")
    private Address address2;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

.

```
package com.perennial.beans.employee;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "address_line1", length = 100)
    private String addressLine1;

    @Column(name = "address_line2", length = 100)
    private String addressLine2;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "zip_code")
    private String zipCode;


    private Employee employee;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }

    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }

    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }


}
```

could any one please tell me how can i do this

Comment: It's not really a response to the issue here. But I think it'll be better to have a list of addresses for the Employee, and add an address type (Enum for example) to the class address. So if you need to add another address it'll be simple.

Comment: @hasnae It will be not convenient to use this approach, for an example with filling addresses on the form.

Comment: basically in form we have only two address Permamnent and Residential. thats why i am doing this

Answer (score 1):

To map exactly to `permanent_address` and `residential_address` you need to change your `Employee` mapping this way

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "permanent_address")
private Address permanentAddress;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "residential_address")
private Address residentialAddress;
```

And you need to add getters and setters for `permanentAddress` and `residentialAddress`  to the `Employee` of course.

**Update**

And it is need to delete this `private Employee employee;` form the `Address` class.

Comment: getting errero :

Could not determine type for: com.perennial.beans.employee.Employee, at table: address, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(employee)]

Comment: solved the issue..thanks. to solve this I have updated Address class also.

Comment: @TipuSultan Sorry man. I didn't notice `private Employee employee` in the `Address`. You can just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

@v.ladynev answer was correct for generating appropriate column name in Employee table.

But the above exception seems because hibernate is not able to understand about the "Employee employee" in ur Address class, as u are not providing any type of it.(like @column/@OneToOne/@embeded).

I think you need to modify your Address class

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address1") // inverse reference for bi-directional mapping of "address1"
private Employee employee1;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address2")  // inverse reference for bi-directional mapping of "address2"
private Employee employee2;
```

But as @hasnae said, it seems not a correct approach, better u create a collection type of Address in Employee with @oneToMany.

And u can have @ManyToOne of Employee in ur Address class.